# Regular Expression issue with detecting function names

Tags: regex

I am writing a syntax highlighter and need to be able to find the Funct1, Funct2, Funct3 in this type of syntax.

```
Integer : Funct1 Integer n  //return type : name Input
    //code
    -> //return
 : Funct2 Integer k //void return
    //code

Class :: BaseClass
    //code
    : Funct3 Integer s
        //code
```

None of the regular expressions that I tried on online regex testing sites worked. Would be very thankful if someone could educate me on how to detect the name of the functions in every one of these cases.

Comment: What are some of the ones that you tried? Will it always be the pattern `functionName, space, Integer, space, single letter`??

Comment: No it is a language so the programmer can make decisions. What will always happen is it will be after a colon

Comment: The real way is to use the parser designed for the language. Since you probably won't do that, try something like `Funct\d+`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=:)\s*(\S+)\s*
```

This worked for me.